# Binding params for PDO statement inside a loop

Tags: php, foreach, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to bind parametres for SQL query inside a loop:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'test', '');  
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO entries VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, NULL)');

$title = 'some titile';
$post = 'some text';
$date = '2010-whatever';  

$reindex = array(1 => $title, $post, $date); // indexed with 1 for bindParam

foreach ($reindex as $key => $value) {  
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);  
    echo "$key</br>$value</br>";  //will output: 1</br>some titile</br>2</br>some text</br>3</br>2010-whatever</br>
}
```

The code above inserts in database in all 3 fields `2010-whatever`.

This one works fine:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $title);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $post);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $date);
```

So, my question is why the code in the foreach-loop fails and inserts wrong data in the fields?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem is that `bindParam` requires a reference.  It binds the variable to the statement, not the value.  Since the variable in a `foreach` loop is unset at the end of each iteration, you can't use the code in the question.

You can do the following, using a reference in the `foreach`:

```
foreach ($reindex as $key => &$value) {  //pass $value as a reference to the array item
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);  // bind the variable to the statement
}
```

Or you could do this, using `bindValue`:

```
foreach ($reindex as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue($key, $value);  // bind the value to the statement
}
```

Comment: Hello Ionesomeday -  I've bumped into a similar problem. Would you be able to lend me a hand with this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285341/php-function-procedure-to-bind-question-marks-dynamically

Comment: The question is - which one is better? bindValue or bindParam.

Comment: @IdanMagled Here I think `bindValue` is more intuitive. `bindParam` offers advantages in some circumstances.

Comment: What does the `&` do in `&$value` ?

Comment: @Taurus It makes `$value` a reference to the array element rather than copying its value.