# Debugging PDO - Why Is a Query Returning No Rows?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that I'm executing with PDO that has bind variables. If I echo out the statement's `queryString` value and substitute the bind variables myself, and execute the query, I get returned rows. I was hoping someone could give me some pointers on debugging this issue.

---

I'm awarding [VMai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501730/vmai)'s answer, because he gave me some good debugging tips. I discovered that in my case the problem was due to using [`bindParam()` in a `foreach` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4174524/244826). Creating a code snippet where the only difference was the `foreach` loop is what got me researching in that direction. I didn't need [the functionality that `bindParam` affords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1179874/244826), so switching to `bindValue` fixed the bug.

Comment: showing some code would be a good start. there's literally an infinite number of reasons it's not working. showing some code will help nail that infinity down to something a wee bit more manageable.

Comment: There are a few layers of abstraction, so showing a relevant code snippet is problematic. I was hoping for more generalized debugging tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PDOStatement::debugDumpParams to get information about the prepared statement, see
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Otherwise you can enable the general query log of your MySQL server in my.cnf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html